# Database 2nd normal form

Tags: database

I have a problem about the 2nd normal form. The rule says : “A relation is in second formal form when it is in 1NF and there is no such non-key
attribute that depends on part of the candidate key, but on the entire candidate key.” (Neeraj Sharma, 2010) My problem is about the candidate key. It is only the primary key of a relation or all possible candidate keys.

Thank you for your help

Comment: That definition of 2NF is not in good English. It isn't clear. One problem is "the CK" since a relation variable/value can have more than one CK. However, unfortuntely that really is a quote from 4.5.2 Second Normal Form (2NF) in Database Fundamentals by Neeraj Sharma et al published 2010 by IBM. Caveat emptor. 2NF is when/iff no non-prime attribute is partially functionally dependent on any CK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It counts for any candidate key.  If it counted only for the primary key, simply adding a surrogate id would be enough to put any table into 3NF.  However, that wouldn't help to ensure that each fact is recorded once only and independent of other facts.

Comment: Well if that’s the case, I think this will bring to a lot decomposition then to suit the 3rd form requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to clear your doubt by an example:

According to 2NF "Partial Dependencies are not allowed in a relation."

Assume this relation: R(A,B,C,D)
lets suppose there are 3 CK's related to this relation (Assume CK's: AB,AC,B).
Then first write all the attributes that are present in any of CK's,these are called Prime attributes.Other than that are called non prime attributes.
Here: 
            Prime Attributes (3)= {A,B,C} 
          Non Prime Attributes (1)={D}
Now According to 2 NF, any FD should not be in this form:

> > > This kind of FD's aren Not allowed in 2NF:
> > >        "Part of any candidate key(Partial Dependency) ---> Non Prime attribute"

Means:
Here : C---> D(Not allowed in 2 NF because C is a part of CK "AC" and D is non prime attribute)

Hope this helps. For more detail, you can also refer : [Detailed explanation of Normal forms](http://ashishparihargatenotes.blogspot.in/2016/03/database-management-system-best-one.html)

Comment: Partial dependencies are allowed. Certain partial dependencies are not allowed. This post is not clear.